# first rewrite rule overriding the rest

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

quick question for those who know a little more about mod-rewrite than i do:

I have some rules written in sequence like so:

```
RewriteRule ^(en|fr) index.php?page=home&lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(en|fr)/home index.php?page=home&lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(en|fr)/terms index.php?page=terms&lang=$1 [L]
```

however the first one seems to be over-riding the rest.

I've tried taking off the `[L]` but this doesnt do what I expected and it will never show the "terms" page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `http://www.example.com/en` or `http://www.example.com/fr/` (with or without trailing slash) to redirect to the first item, change the first rule to be:

`RewriteRule ^(en|fr)/?$ index.php?page=home&lang=$1 [L]`

The `/?` matches whether or not there's a trailing slash and the `$` means "match the end of the URL" (don't match if the URL continues).